# Can i join mysql with hive?

Tags: mysql, hive, hdfs

Can I join tables between `mysql` and hive (hive on `hdfs`)?

Somebody tell me it works between `mysql` and oracle.

Example:

```
SELECT a.* FROM a JOIN b ON (a.id = b.id)
```

a is in `mysql`, when b is in hive on `hdfs`.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you could not use Hive to join table sitting in MySQL/Oracle with table in HDFS.

As a workaround you could use [Sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org) to get the table(s) from MySQL/Oracle to Hive and then join them both within Hive.

For example if you have a table named `a` in MySQL, you could use Sqoop to get the table into hive like so:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/yourDBName \
   --username root -P \
   --table a \
   --hive-import \
   --hive-table a \
   -m 1
```

Once, the import gets completed you can join two tables assuming `b` is your other table in Hive:

```
SELECT a.* FROM a JOIN b ON (a.id = b.id)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Spark to do the same

```
val mysqlDF = spark
                .read
                .jdbc(url, tablename, props) 

val hiveDF = spark
                .read
                .table(tablename)
```

then you can join those DF and perform your logic

Also you can write the mysqlDF to a table

```
 mysqlDF.write.saveAsTable(tablename2)
```

You can join the 2 tables from the spark-sql cli `spark-sql>`

Comment: I think this is the correct answer as per the question. There is no point pulling  the data to hadoop and do the join.

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late to comments - but nevertheless: 
**Presto comes with this built in capability**. It uses catalogs and schemas to achieve this.

> Presto allows querying data where it lives, including Hive, Cassandra, relational databases or even proprietary data stores. A single Presto query can combine data from multiple sources, allowing for analytics across your entire organization.

--from https://prestodb.io/